# How do I display only the selected values in combobox when I upload it to the database with javafx

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

So the problem I have right now is that I'm able to update my database with new users, but it doesn't display the right data for the role column, as it's from a combobox selections, it display the whole combo box choice instead of just the selected one. Problem as shown in the link below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwqrv.jpg

**AddUsers Method**

```java
public static void addUsers(String username, String password, String role, String staff_id) {

try {
            Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();

            String sql = "INSERT into Login(username, password, role, staff_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, username);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ps.setString(3, role);
            ps.setString(4, staff_id);

            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

**ObservableList for the userRoleBox**

```java
ObservableList<String> userRoleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Admin", "Technician", "Finance", "Management", "Customer Services");
```

**Initialize the comboBox**

```java
@FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
     userRoleBox.setValue("Technician");
     userRoleBox.setItems(userRoleList);
    }
```

The method that initialize when the click the confirm button to add the users into the database

```java
    @FXML
    public void ConfirmUsers(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        if(usernametxtfld.getText().isEmpty() || passwordtxtfld.getText().isEmpty() || userRoleBox.getItems().isEmpty() || staffIDtxtfld.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            Alert errorAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            errorAlert.setHeaderText("Please fill in all of the fields");
            errorAlert.setContentText("Click OK and ensure you have entered information in all of the boxes.");
            errorAlert.showAndWait();

        }
        else{

            CreateUsersDAO.addUsers(usernametxtfld.getText(),passwordtxtfld.getText(),userRoleBox.getItems().toString(),staffIDtxtfld.getText());
            clearFields();
            Alert confirmation = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            confirmation.setHeaderText("New user has been added.");
            confirmation.showAndWait();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get selected `combo box` value like below :

```
userRoleBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();//will give you single item selected
```

Change your parameter in function this `userRoleBox.getItems().toString()` to `userRoleBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();`

For more info refer **[ComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html)**